# rust what does a failed compare exchange on AtomicPtr return?

Tags: rust

So in rust, I am trying to see what result is given when a `AtomicPtr.compare_exchange()` fails, where the expected value is not what is actually contained. I have the following code:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, Ordering};

pub fn foo() {
    let ptr = &mut 5;
    let ptr2 = &mut 6;
    let atomic_ptr = AtomicPtr::new(ptr);
    unsafe {
        match atomic_ptr.compare_exchange(ptr, ptr2, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst) {
            Ok(got) => println!("Worked got {}", *got),
            Err(nogot) => println!("Failed got {}", *nogot),
        }
    }
}

pub fn bar() {
    let ptr = &mut 5;
    let ptr2 = &mut 6;
    let atomic_ptr = AtomicPtr::new(ptr);
    unsafe {
        match atomic_ptr.compare_exchange(ptr2, ptr2, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst) {
            Ok(got) => println!("Worked got {}", *got),
            Err(nogot) => println!("Failed got {}", *nogot),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

But this prints

```
Worked got 5
Failed got 5
```

It seems both success and fail for the compare exchange give the currently held pointer. Is this truly the case? Or am I missing something here? The docs don't document what the `Result` gives on failure either https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html#method.compare_exchange

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Make your `unsafe` block as small as possible, in this case dont wrap your whole `match` into an `unsafe` block, but instead just the dereferencing of your pointers, e.g. `println!("Worked got {}", unsafe { *got })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems both success and fail for the compare exchange give the currently held pointer. Is this truly the case?

Yes.

> The docs don't document what the Result gives on failure either

They do, though the wording obscures it:

> The return value is a result indicating whether the new value was written and containing the previous value. On success this value is guaranteed to be equal to current.

This is actually 3 completely separate clauses:

- the return value is a result indicating whether the new value was written (`Ok`) -- implies that it's an `Err` on failure
- the return value contains the previous value -- regardless of success
- on success the the return value is guaranteed equal to `current` -- obviously on failure the `current` you provided was wrong, so you get something else (the actual current value)

Either opening a documentation issue or a documentation PR to clarify this would probably be welcome, though beware that this issue seems to be duplicated on all three implementations of `compare_exchange` so you'll probably have to fix them all if you go the PR route: all integer types are implemented via a common macro but `AtomicPtr` and `AtomicBool` have their own copies of the entire interface.